# Instantiating object using incompletely initialized 'this' as parameter

Tags: java

Assume I have a Warehouse class.  That Warehouse has a TradeDesk.  That TradeDesk computes available items to sell based on an instance variable set in Warehouse.  A Warehouse's constructor instantiates a TradeDesk, but because TradeDesk needs an instance variable from the incompletely initialized Warehouse, we have a problem.  Short of passing the instance value through multiple constructors (which I'd rather avoid; note that the below example is significantly simplified), how do I solve this?  Thanks!

```
public class Warehouse {
    TradingDesk td;
    public int val;

    public Warehouse() {
        val = 3;
        td = new TradingDesk(this);
    }
// New class
public class TradingDesk {
    Warehouse associatedWh;
    int val;
    public TradingDesk(Warehouse wh) {
        associatedWh = wh;
        val = associatedWh.val;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have a bit of a problem.  The JVM spec prohibits "releasing" a pointer to an incompletely constructed object.  There are strict rules on this and they're pretty airtight.

Comment: Moreover, due to the JMM (Java Memory Model) conception, your code is not thread-safe at all because you escape the `this`object before constructor ends.

Comment: I completely understand the issues you're bringing up.  I want to avoid having to call multiple methods, however (e.g. construct, and then perform computations).  It makes sense that computation should occur during the construction of my TradingDesk, but it's reliant on an instance variable in the uninitialized Warehouse.  What's the "right thing to do" in this situation?

Comment: @Walker Your edited code is wrong. Once you use an inner class you have no need to pass the enclosing class instance. You can access its state directly. There isno need for the `associatedWith` field.

Comment: Is the circular reference necessary? If I understand the problem correctly, a Warehouse is a representation of a store for items, and a TradeDesk represents the point of sale of those items. Conceptually a Warehouse needs to have no prior knowledge of how it's items are sold to be able to store them and so doesn't need to know about the TradeDesk. A TradeDesk needs to know what items are available for sale and needs access (directly or otherwise) to the Warehouse. Refactoring your code may solve your problem. Circular dependencies also have the problem of what to do at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your inner-class code, you attempt to initialize the `Warehouse` field with the instance of the outer class.
So code becomes:

```
public class Warehouse {
    private TradingDesk td = new TradingDesk();
    private int val = 3;

    class TradingDesk {
         // you have already access to the outer Warehouse class including its fields
    }
}
```

Indeed, an inner-class have access to all properties of the outer class.
So your issue disappears.

**EDIT------------------**

Here my solution to deal with the circular dependency:

```
public class Warehouse {
    private TradingDesk td = new TradingDesk();
    private int val = 3;

    public int getVal(){ //so accessible through TradingDesk object
        return val;
    }

    public void associateWhToTd(){
        td.setAssociatedWh(this); // no issue here since "this" is fully already created
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){ // example of usage
        Warehouse wh = new Warehouse();
        wh.associateWhToTd();
    }
}

public class TradingDesk {
    Warehouse associatedWh;

    public void setAssociatedWh(Warehouse wh){
       this.associatedWh = wh;
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the code; in an effort to simplify, I wrote my example using an inner class, but not all classes I'm dealing with will be inner.  Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could make of `TradingDesk` an inner class of `WareHouse`. This way it will have direct access to its enclosing `WareHouse` instance variables without the need of passing any parameters and it will be possible to create instances of it only within the context of a `WareHouse` instance.

```
public class Warehouse {

    private int val;
    private TradingDesk td;

    public Warehouse() {
        this.val = 3;
        this.td = new TradingDesk();
    }

    public class TradingDesk {

        public TradingDesk() {
            //this is the right way to access the enclosing instance
           if(WareHouse.this.val==3){
               //do something
           }
        }

        public WareHouse getAssociatedWareHouse(){
           return WareHouse.this;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lazily instantiated child object:

```
class Warehouse {
  private TradingDesk td;
  ...

  public Warehouse() {
    ...
  }

  public TradingDesk getTradingDesk() {
    if (td == null) td = new TradingDesk(this);
    return td;
  }
}
```

Just be aware that the above getter is not thread safe.

[Don't escape `this` during construction](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618/index.html).